# Как упорядочить слова в лексикографическом порядке?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Всем привет!

Необходимо решить следующую задачу

> Ввести N строк. Упорядочить и вывести строки в порядке возрастания
>   значений их длины. В случае, если длины строк совпадают - упорядочить
>   их в лексикографическом порядке

Написал код для упорядочивания строк.

**Вопрос:** как реализовать вывод одинаковых по длине строк в лексикографическом порядке не могу понять.

```
public static void task2() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    String[] strings = new String[n];

    //Считываем строки
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        strings[i] = reader.readLine();
    }

    //Сортировка массива методом пузырька
    for (int i = strings.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (strings[j].length() > strings[j + 1].length()) {
                String max = strings[j];
                strings[j] = strings[j + 1];
                strings[j + 1] = max;
            }
        }
    }
    //Вывод элементов массива
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("(" + strings[i].length() + ")" + ":" + " " + "\"" + strings[i] + "\"");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.compareTo(String)
```

Вероятно то, что вы ищете. Сравнивает строки лексикографически, возвращает целое число, 0 если строки равны, > 0, если эта строка больше, и < 0, если эта строка меньше аргумента.

Только учитывайте, что данный метод отдает приоритет лексикографии, нежели длине, и если вы хотите сделать приоритетнее длину, то сравнивайте по длине отдельно и до лексикографии.

P.S. вы можете использовать `ArrayList` или `LinkedList`, а для сортировки воспользоваться методом `sort`:

```
myList.sort((s1, s2) -> {
    if(s1.length != s2.length)
        return s1.length - s2.length;
    else
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
});
```