# Как отсортировать список объектов по их параметрам, по возрастанию. На примере одного параметра

Tags: java, сортировка, arraylist

```
    ArrayList<Aircraft> planesOfAirline = new ArrayList<Aircraft>();

    planesOfAirline.add(new Light("AN-32", 7, 5200, 780, 1000));
    planesOfAirline.add(new Middle("AN-70", 47, 55000, 6600, 3500));
    planesOfAirline.add(new Middle("A400M", 37, 44000, 6400, 4000));
    planesOfAirline.add(new Heavy("AN-124", 120, 132000, 4800, 12600));
    planesOfAirline.add(new Heavy("AN-225", 250, 198000, 4000, 19000));
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как упорядочить слова в лексикографическом порядке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582549/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635518/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-arraylistchat-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-chat?rq=1

Comment: Есть такая штука, как компаратор. Вы можете создать сколько угодно своих классов-компараторов для работы с любой сущностью. А вызывая Collections.sort в параметрах передавать коллекцию, типизированную указанной сущностью и компаратор, определяющий вид сортировки. Таким образом, вызывая Collections.sort для одной коллекции, но с разными компараторами можно выполнять сортировку любыми способами.